# .NET CF - Unused Image Property causes code generation error at design time

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework

First please note this is .NET Compact Framework 3.5 in Visual Studio 2008

I have a property in a User Control as follows:

```
   Private _image2 As Image
   Public Property Image2() As Image
       Get
           Return _image2
       End Get
       Set(ByVal value As Image)        
               _image2 = value 
       End Set
   End Property
```

When the property is null/nothing I get the following error in the form designer using the control:

> Code generation for property 'Image2' failed. Error was: 'Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.'

**The property is not referenced** by any code in the control or the form.

The error is not in the paint method or constructor.

If I add the foloowing to the get method prevents the error:

```
If _image2 Is Nothing Then
    Return New Bitmap(1, 1)
End If
```

However this isn't good and means my paint method cannot tell if an image is set or not.

I also get the same error with a null/nothing font property.

Is there any way to allow a null/nothing image/font property?

Comment: Try As Nullable(Of Image) for the member var and the property. The designer will access the Property although you did not code that. You may also use Bitmap(1,1) as inicator for a non-set image in your code.

Comment: You may also use Bitmap(1,1) as inicator for a non-set image in your code: Private _image2 As Image = new Bitmap(1,1)

Comment: @josef Can't use Nullable(of Image) as Image is not a struct.
"Type 'System.Drawing.Image' must be a value type or a type argument constrained to 'Structure' in order to be used with 'Nullable' or nullable modifier '?'."

Comment: Using Bitmap(1,1)  does seem to be the only option. Just have to be careful and make sure it's disposed otherwise memory leaks.